# How do we create timeseries collections with mongodb golang driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, time-series, mongo-go

I am trying to create timeseries collections => https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/#expireafterseconds with the following function
As you can see below i have tried different iterations to pass options to the `CreateCollection()` but nothing works. Searched for hours for an example of this and could not find any, and one would think will be easy to setup based on current documentation but hours later and here to get help

```
func CollectionsTimeSeries(name string) {

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

    // options := {
    //  "TimeSeriesOptions": {
    //      "TimeField": "time_stamp",
    //      "MetaField": "stock",
    //      "Granularity": "minutes",
    //  },
    //  "ExpireAfterSeconds": 2592000,      
    // }

    // options := { 
    //  timeseries: {
    //      timeField: "time_stamp",
    //      metaField: "stock",
    //      granularity: "minutes",
    //  },
    //  expireAfterSeconds: 2592000         
    // }

    options := { 
    "timeseries": {
        "timeField": "time_stamp",
        "metaField": "stock",
        "granularity": "minutes",
    },
    "expireAfterSeconds": 2592000       
    }

    // database.GetConnection.CreateCollection(ctx, name, { 
    //  timeseries: {
    //      timeField: "time_stamp",
    //      metaField: "stock",
    //      granularity: "minutes",
    //  },
    //  expireAfterSeconds: 2592000         
    // })


    database.GetConnection.CreateCollection(ctx, name, options)
}
```

Get the following errors

```
syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression
syntax error: unexpected }, expecting comma or )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`options`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.0/mongo/options) package to create an options instance containing time series options:

```
opt:=options.CreateCollection().
   SetTimeseriesOptions(options.TimeSeries().
        SetGranularity("...").
        SetMetaField("...").
        SetTimeField("..."))
```

Comment: where did you get the documentation to do it this way?

Comment: See the package documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.8.2/mongo/options

Comment: weird am getting this new error now `database.GetConnection.CreateCollection undefined (type func() (*mongo.Client, error) has no field or method CreateCollection)` but am using latest mongo-go driver...but using `mongodb 4.4.12` because of the AUX issue with using `mongodb 5` and above (https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-5-0-cpu-intel-g4650-compatibility/116610
)

Comment: Based on the error, `GetConnection` is a function, so you should call it. I don't see a GetConnectoin function in MongoDB driver documents

Comment: issue is not in `GetConnection`, that is a function i have...issue is with `has no field or method CreateCollection` and i think issue has to be with mongodb and driver compatibility...will fix that issue and test soon

Comment: The error is telling that database.GetConnection does not have a field or method called CreateConnection. The error is also telling that GetConnection is a function.

Comment: ok will test things out in a bit

Comment: Minor typo: "SetTimeseriesOptions" should be "SetTimeSeriesOptions"

Comment: @uberrebu TimeSeries is a `MongoDB 5.0` [feature](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/#time-series-collections). That would explain why the driver is displaying an error when trying to create a TimeSeries collection on `MongoDB 4.4`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a TimeSerie collection with the method: `(*mongo.Database).CreateCollection`

That function allows (optional) arguments of type `*options.CreateCollectionOptions` that you can have by doing: `options.CreateCollection()` and then call its methods to fill the option you want. One of them is: `(*options.CreateCollectionOptions).SetTimeSeriesOptions`.

So far your code should looks like:

```golang
database.CreateCollection(
    context.TODO(), 
    "newCollection", 
    options.CreateCollection().SetTimeSeriesOptions(
        options.TimeSeries(),
    ),
)
```

with `options.TimeSeries()` you have methods to set up your time series collection juste like it is done with `options.CreateCollection()`.

However (unfortunately) I don't think it is possible to create a time series collection with `(*mongo.Database).Collection`. That function use the option: `*options.CollectionOptions`.